# How can I send screenshots more quickly in Skype?

Tags: skype, file-transfer, screenshot

It's so long and complicated to open Paint/Photoshop/whatever and saving a file somewhere, then dragging it to Skype just send a screenshot to a friend through Skype! How can I speed up the process? Do I need an external app?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't.

1. Press the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button when your computer is in the desired state to take the screenshot.
2. Go back to Skype. With your writing cursor (the flashing thing) inside the message typing field, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the pixels into your Skype conversation. Alternatively, right-click the field and select **Paste**.

   You should see a small version of your screenshot in the field now.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Skype will create a PNG file named with a timestamp and send it.

Notes:

- You **cannot** send text and screenshots in a single message. If a message contains a screenshot, the text will be **deleted** and only the screenshot sent. Be careful!
- You **can** send multiple screenshots through this method. Just paste them one after the other and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- This function is not limited to screenshots. Some applications in which you can copy or cut pixels will allow you to paste your clipboard into Skype just the same, such as **Adobe Photoshop** (tested with CS6, 64-bit version). **Paint**, however, does not allow this.
- All images sent through this method are archived in `C:\Users\<YOUR USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\My Skype Received Files`. You can access those files anytime through either:

  - Double-clicking the image icon to the left of the file transfer entry in your Skype conversation; or
  - Browsing to the folder.

  Note that AppData is a hidden folder, and that by default, it might not appear to you. You can remedy to that in `Control Panel -> Folder Options`.
- Screenshot software that disable the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key's default behaviour and, for example, create a file on the desktop, might make this impossible, since they do not put pixels in your clipboard.
- This trick is not available on the Mac OS or Linux versions of Skype.
- To the best of my knowledge, this has been possible since the version 5 of Skype, at the very least.

Comment: I could not get the Mac version of Skype (v6.9) to paste an image from the clipboard.  The Mac version will paste text from the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @bbarnhart. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in the Linux version of Skype either, sadly.

Comment: Sad. Aw well, Microsoft software. Probably roughly the same reason why iTunes doesn't exactly work perfectly on Windows.

Comment: Not work for me with Windows 7 's Skype application

Comment: It should, really. If it doesn't, some other program might be changing the behavior of your PrintScreen key or, less likely, the paste function itself. Or perhaps you've put some special plugins in Skype?

Comment: [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) also allows you to copy/cut pixels and paste them on Skype

Comment: If you hold alt and print screen, it will only print the active window (application)

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/), you need to add `Windows Bitmap` to the clipboard formats to enable the paste into Skype (I use Skype version 6.22.0.107).

In `Greenshot`, go to `Preferences` and click on the `Expert tab`.  There, select the `"I know what I'm doing" checkbox` and from the checkbox list on the right select `Windows Bitmap`.

[image]

Comment: This is the one I need with Greenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I use GreenShot. Take screenshot, upload/edit/save/copy to clipboard with just 1 keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Does this work with Skype as well? What does the workflow look like? How do Greenshot's additional features help in that particular situation?

Comment: The way I work is this: Press Prnt Scrn, select the region, a short menu pops up, select Upload to Imgur, a second later, the link to the image is copied to your clipboard. Share!

Comment: You both should definitely have a look at Greenshot's blog post about how to send screenshot to skype with the external command plugin. You can set Skype as target destination using the plugin, then it's just a single click to send the screenshot to skype.
No need to use the clipboard :)

http://getgreenshot.org/2013/02/17/how-to-send-an-image-to-skype-using-command-line-arguments/

Comment: I dunno. I cannot think of anything simpler than print-screen, alt-tab, ctrl-v. Not to mention it doesn't require any additional software.

Comment: This depends on how often you need to do screenshots. If you work with screenshots every day and can make use of enhanced features (like quick annotations etc), it is well worth considering to install software to do these things. After all, hitting Print-Screen and directly selecting a destination for the screenshot *is* simpler than Print-Screen, focus another program, paste. That said, Skype definitely has great image-from-clipboard support, most other software embeds a huge Windows bitmap instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found that bmp format img would paste directly in skype. So like the snipaste by check on "Copy as Windows Bitmap", then it works fine.

Snipaste preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this cannot (currently) be done from the Mac version of Skype for Business :(